# Different result between Q# and Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, grovers-algorithm, q#

I'm running a search program with custom initial state. I wrote a program in Q# and one in Qiskit but I get different results even if the code seems to be peforming the same operations. The Q# result is correct according to my calculations while the Qiskit one is not. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong in Qiskit?
The Boolean function is  (not reg[0] or reg[2]) and (not reg[1] or reg[2]) and (not reg[0] or not reg[1]) and reg[3]  and I'm measuring only the first 3 bits (reg[0] to reg[2]).
Here is the Q# code https://gist.github.com/friguzzi/833ded93a640ed97a3b281c5542e90ea
and Qiskit python notebook https://gist.github.com/friguzzi/6293793de3d53914dac9e1cb768f9817
The correct result should be 101 but the output of Qiskit over 1000 runs is

```
 {'000': 179,
 '001': 135,
 '010': 36,
 '011': 41,
 '100': 152,
 '101': 167,
 '110': 165,
 '111': 125}
```

Comment: This might be a difference in my personal opinion, but typically sifting through entire files of code is not as effective as pointing to specific sections that you think might be causing the problems. Do you have any leads?

Comment: I would start by removing the last qubit from the program - if you're not looking for its value, it just offers more potential space to introduce a bug and makes observing the state harder. Second, I'd go through both programs step by step, dump their states (DumpMachine in Q#, not sure what's the equivalent in Qiskit) and compare them - once they diverge, you know where the problem is. After that you can either identify it yourself or ask a more educated question that narrows down the area to search, as @C.Kang suggested.

Comment: (On a second thought, I'd measure the last qubit together with the first three - removing it will change the probability success of the algorithm so not the best thing for troubleshooting)

Comment: Would you be able to share the complete Q# code that you used to test, including the csproj file? When I run the code at the provided gist, I get that there's no operation called QPME; changing line 18 of Driver.cs to `Search.Run` results in a similar histogram to the one that you quoted from Qiskit:

Key: [Zero,One,One], Value: 157
Key: [One,One,One], Value: 164
Key: [Zero,Zero,Zero], Value: 182
Key: [Zero,Zero,One], Value: 143
Key: [One,Zero,One], Value: 161
Key: [Zero,One,Zero], Value: 20
Key: [One,Zero,Zero], Value: 124
Key: [One,One,Zero], Value: 49

Comment: As a side note, in addition to the DumpMachine functionality that @MariiaMykhailova mentioned, one thing I often find helpful when debugging is to use `within` and `apply` to make sure that I don't make mistakes when writing out $U^{\dagger} V U$-style patterns. For example, `ApplyMarkingOracleAsPhaseOracle` can be written as `within { H(target); X(target); } apply { markingOracle(register, target); }`.

Comment: Hi, I run again both programs and I think the results are similar, I believe they are inside the statistical variation. One problem was that qiskit order qubits the opposite with respect to Q# so I was misunderstanding the results.